# Cannot inspect an element with chrome debug tools

Tags: html, google-chrome, debugging

I'm a web developer and I'm looking to analyze the behavior of a web page. Please note that I've just started working on the project and don't know the code in depth.

My page contains a form with front-end validation that the required text fields have been filled in.

When I click on the submit button, a tooltip appears. My aim is to locate this tooltip in the html page and analyze its attributes: class name, id, css, etc.

I tried to locate it and analyze it with chrome debug tools. However, I can't visualize this tooltip in my html, nor select it with the element inspector.

Even reading the code, I can't figure out where this tooltip comes from.

Do you have any idea how I can go about inspecting this html element?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that sounds as if you were not dealing with a tooltip _explicitly implemented_ by the site developer in own code, but probably simply with HTML5 Form Validation ...?

Comment: Does the project use any CSS Library such as Bootstrap ? 
Can you post the related HTML Code ? At least the element on which the tooltip appears

Comment: Try adding a screenshot, that will give more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're triggering the HTML5 form validation. They will look different in dependence of your current browser.

To disable this validation you need to add the `novalidate` attribute to your form: `<form novalidate>` .

This way you would disable the HTML5 form validation but you'll need to implement your own validation method. For this you could use a frontend validation framework like [validatejs](https://validatejs.org/)

You're also free to implement your own validation for this:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('yourForm').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        let yourElement = document.getElementById('yourElement');

        if (!yourElement.checkValidity()) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevents the form from submission
            alert('This field is mandatory.');
        }
    });
</script>
```